# Why do IPA pronunciations pronounce phones in two ways? 1st on their own. 2nd with a vowel /ɑ/ or schwa in front?

Tags: ipa

I use IPA and ***oral cavity videos (is this the correct term?)*** to master phonemes, while I learn second languages. Examples are

- [[ ʎ̝ ] voiced dorsal palatal lateral fricative](https://youtu.be/bsCpUD4sURg), [[ ʝ ] voiced dorsal palatal non sibilant fricative](https://youtu.be/jXY5wj56kQY) — by Glossika Phonics.
- [ʎ](https://youtu.be/pkFp5eVNtDk), [ʝ](https://youtu.be/v_MqaAyy4WY) —  by UBC Visible Speech.

Neither sounds like [ə]! ʎ can be analogized most closely to [`LLI` in mi`LLI`on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Spanish).  [ʝ] to ["⟨y⟩ in English *your*, but with stronger friction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo#Pronunciation), or [`y` in `y`ou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo#Pronunciation).

Which is the first phone in front?  vowel [ɑ] or schwa [ə]?

Why do they preface phones with this vowel [ɑ] or schwa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many consonant sounds can't be pronounced in isolation. Stops, for example, are defined by completely stopping the airflow—hence the name. And if there's not something else going on at the same time (like air being allowed to flow out through the nose), that sounds like complete silence.

So for consistency, consonants are usually demonstrated by putting them first before a vowel, and then between vowels: `[Ca aCa]`. The exact vowel used doesn't matter, but is conventionally low and central.

Comment: The vowel does matter to some degree. Using high front vowels would likely cause some degree of palatalisation, shifting the consonant away from its canonical location, for example – hence the low central vowel, which is least likely to have ‘side effects’.

Comment: it is somewhat surprising that the pattern [Ca aCa aC] isn't used. Obviously there are plenty of languages with highly restricted codas, but being able to hear the consonant pronounced in coda would certainly be useful

Comment: I came across a funny situation on the Spanish site re the pronunciation of a consonant sound. When I tried to tell them about the fact that something has to follow at the end of the sound, they shot me down. :) +1 The Spanish speakers were trying to tell me that the **n** in a word like nene (baby) can be drawn out indefinitely, and I said no, only the e sound following the initial pronunciation of n as ne can be drawn out.

Comment: @Lambie I think extending an N sound is a lot like humming, which is certainly possible. I've certainly seen English texts use "Nnnnno" to transcribe someone lingering on the N sound to give a hesitant denial.

Comment: @Amalloy Here was the word: jallapeño. I fail to see how one can extend that ñ sound without the o after it. One thing is what happens in fact and another is a description (your Nnnnno) that missed the sound reality. People seem to have great trouble understanding Draconis' point. Try it: linger on the n in no, as if saying: Nooooo. You can linger on the o, not the n. No sound occurs. The consonants are heard because of the vowels, in effect.

Comment: I did try it before writing the message, and it sounds like humming. Feels like a buzzing on the top of my mouth, kinda middle/back, with slightly open lips and my tongue pressed against my teeth. It's reminiscent of lingering on the m in hmmmmmmm. It's not the same sound as an un-lengthened n at the beginning of "no", which as you say has basically no sound of its own. But I don't think it's crazy to say that you can draw out an N-like sound for use at the beginning of a word.

Comment: @Lambie - [n] and other nasals are sounds that _can_ be pronounced without any vowel, they can be syllabic, even in English 'written' can be pronounced as [ˈɹɪʔ.t̚n̩] with the 2nd syllable [t̚n̩] with the syllabic [n̩] whose only difference from [n] in "no" being the ability to have no vowel around, acoustically the two Ns are the same.  Also note that in Standard Chinese (Mandarin) one of the ways to say "yes" is _n4_ [n̩˥˧], another one is _ng4_ [ŋ̩˥˧] (these are interjections, no standard Chinese characters for them),

Comment: @YellowSky One certainly **cannot prolong** the ñ nasal sound  or any other n sound without some sort of vowel sound. And your written example with [t̚n̩] in final position does not count in terms of prolongation. Once you hear the buzzing sound when you attempt it, you are no longer making a sound associated with an n, you are in the land of imitating wasps or bees.